# How to export data from the Developer console?

Tags: developer-console, tooling-api

I have to remove around 300 inactive flows from our Salesforce org, for this reason I would like to export the results of a query from the developer console to a csv or text. I'm unable to use Workbench since I'm working with the tooling API.
 Thanks!!

[image: Results from the query]

Comment: One other option, if you have `sfdx` installed, is to use its [query function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm#cli_reference_soql_query) with the `-t` switch to use the Tooling API, eg: `sfdx force:data:soql -t -q "SELECT Id, VersionNumber, Status FROM Flow WHERE Status NOT IN ('Active','Draft')" -r csv > results.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't export data from the Developer Console. You can, however, export data via workbench. Go to Utilities > Rest Explorer, and use the following URL:

```
/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query?q=select%20id%2Cversionnumber%2Cstatus%20from%20flow%20where%20status%20not%20in%20('active'%2C'draft')
```

This will return the information you're looking for in a way you can copy-paste in JSON format. You can then use some sort of tool or script to convert to a CSV file for further processing. You can also do this in Apex, and process the results with JSON.deserializeUntyped or JSON.deserialize.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!!